# Looping through an ArrayList in JSP (Struts)

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

I am trying to convert my simple jsp-servlet application to struts. I am able to forward an ArrayList from the Java Class to my JSP, but how do I loop through it?

Adding some code, I have an ArrayList of Strings that I need to forward to the page and then store all of it into a JavaScript Array. Earlier I was using this,

```
<% ArrayList<String> request = new ArrayList<String>();
request = (ArrayList<String>) (request.getAttribute("requests"));
%>

<script>
  var requestlog = new Array();
     <%
        for ( int i = 0; i < request.size(); i++ ) {
     %>
         requestlog.push('<%= request.get(i) %>');

     <% } %> 
</script>
```

Any ideas as to how to go about it now would be very welcome. 
I can access the ArrayList's specific members with
var abc = '< s:property value="requests.get(0)" / >';
But how do I loop through it and store all of it?
Thanks.

Comment: See if this post helps you get an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754939/how-do-you-iterate-through-a-list-of-objects

Answer (score 0):

After converting into struts, you can make use of struts logic tags. Set your list value either via **actionform** by setter method or **session**, then you can use `<logic:present>` tag to check the list present inside of your jsp form and use `<logic:iterate>` tag to iterate through your list based on property. For sample implementation checkout [My Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607882/retaining-form-values-for-dropdown/19611142#19611142). Let me know if this helps.

Comment: the OP is asking for Struts-2 and not Struts-1. it helps looking at the tags as well.